# Neo4j Cypher : transfer all relationships before replacing a node by another

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j.rb

I'm trying to transfert all ingoing and outgoing relationships from a node to another, before deleting the first one. they both have the same label.
I saw this [Neo4j Cypher: copy relationships and delete node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21634936/neo4j-cypher-copy-relationships-and-delete-node)
but in my case i don't know the type of the relations and i want to transfer both ingoing and outgoing ones.

i'm looking for either a cypher query or a query based on neo4j.rb

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that this is possible with pure cypher.  Here's a solution using neo4j.rb that I think will work:

```
# Assuming node1 already loaded
node_query = Neo4j::Session.query.match(node: {neo_id: node1.neo_id})

types = node_query.match('node-[rel]-()').pluck('DISTINCT type(rel)')

types.each do |type|
  node_query.match('node-[rel]->(other)').with(:node, :rel, :other).create("node-[new_rel]->other").set('new_rel = rel').exec
  node_query.match('node<-[rel]-(other)').with(:node, :rel, :other).create("node<-[new_rel]-other").set('new_rel = rel').exec
end
```

Comment: i got the types, but then in the each loop i'm not sure how to specify the other node for the new_rel.
thanks again Brian;)

Comment: Just editing because the second query was going in the wrong direction and they both needed an `exec`

Comment: The other node is getting specified by the `other` variable.  That should be passed through in the `WITH` clause and then matched on again in the `CREATE` clause.  I could be misunderstanding...

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm still struggling with that. assuming node1 and node2 are loaded, we want to transfer relationships from node1 to node2. how would you use the `WITH` clause in this case ?

Comment: The two lines inside of the `each` are generating cypher queries.  The `with` in the middle of the method call chain is what generates the `WITH` part of the cypher clause.  I'm not 100% sure that using the with will copy the properties of the one rel to the other, but I saw somebody using the same technique on another SO post

Comment: i half way now. i can transfer Neo4j::ActiveRel but not undeclared relationships. i tried another way and i had to add a test on rel.to_node to know if it is a Neo4j::ActiveRel. i still don't know how to transfer the other ones

`    relations = self.rels(dir: :outgoing)
    relations.each do |rel|
      if defined? rel.to_node
        new_node.create_rel(rel.type, rel.to_node, rel.props)
      end
    end

    relations = self.rels(dir: :incoming)
    relations.each do |rel|
      if defined? rel.from_node
        rel.from_node.create_rel(rel.type, new_node, rel.props)
      end
    end `

Comment: This is starting to get a bit crowded for comments, maybe open up a new question?

Comment: indeed, done : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274009/neo4j-rb-transfer-all-relationships-before-replacing-a-node-by-another